# What all Internet voice chat applications work in Oman (Preferably free)?

Tags: telephone, oman

Oman currently blocks Skype, Facetime, Viber and a lot of other VOIP applications. Google hangouts works sporadically. Anyone have a good and free voice chat application which is not blocked? I do not want to get a VPN subscription.

Comment: While staying connected can be interesting in various parts of the world, this question is more about software - the network doesn't care about your status as an expat, it just blocks everyone indiscriminately.